# Loading XML from Web Service

Tags: xml, web-services, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I am connecting to a web service to get some data back out as xml. The connection works fine and it returns the xml data from the service.

```
var remoteURL = EveApiUrl;

var postData = string.Format("userID={0}&apikey={1}&characterID={2}", UserId, ApiKey, CharacterId);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteURL);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// Setup a stream to write the HTTP "POST" data
var WebEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
var byte1 = WebEncoding.GetBytes(postData);
var newStream = request.GetRequestStream();

newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
newStream.Close();

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
var webdata = readStream.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(webdata);
```

This prints out the xml that comes from the service. I can also save the xml as an xml file like so;

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Projects\TrainingSkills.xml");
writer.WriteLine(webdata);
writer.Close();
```

Now I can load the file as an XDocument to perform queries on it like this;

```
var data = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Projects\TrainingSkills.xml");
```

What my problem is that I don't want to save the file and then load it back again. When I try to load directly from the stream I get an exception, **Illegal characters in path**. I don't know what is going on, if I can load the same xml as a text file why can't I load it as a stream.

The xml is like this;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2010-04-28 17:58:27</currentTime>
  <result>
    <currentTQTime offset="1">2010-04-28 17:58:28</currentTQTime>
    <trainingEndTime>2010-04-29 02:48:59</trainingEndTime>
    <trainingStartTime>2010-04-28 00:56:42</trainingStartTime>
    <trainingTypeID>3386</trainingTypeID>
    <trainingStartSP>8000</trainingStartSP>
    <trainingDestinationSP>45255</trainingDestinationSP>
    <trainingToLevel>4</trainingToLevel>
    <skillInTraining>1</skillInTraining>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2010-04-28 18:58:27</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Lukasz, just a tip: If you're going to use this in production, throw in some error handling code and make sure you close your connections and streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're trying to use:

```
string xml = GetXmlFromService();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xml);
```

That's trying to load it as if the XML was a filename!

Instead, you want

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

Alternatively, use

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(textReader);
```

or

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Comment: XDocument.Parse works... Don't know why I didn't try that! Thanks!